# Identify symmetry of a matrix [ ] [ ]

Tags: java, matrix, symmetry

I'm trying to find if a matrix [][] is symmetric in different orientations (horitzonzal/ vertical or both), and found this tutorial 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-horizontal-vertical-symmetry-binary-matrix/  and tried it with my matrixes, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. 
Here is my current code and the output I get:

Example Matrix:

```
111
144
144
```

I call the method from the tutorial by:

```
 // test for symmetrie 
    checkHV(matrix, rows, colums);
```

Where rows and colums in this case are both 3.
From my opinion, it should output NO, but the current output is VERTICAL (always, with all matrixes..). Why is that? And how could I modify the code so that it works correctly for me? Thanks!

And here the code from the tutorial:

```
 static void checkHV(int [][]arr, int N,
                int M)
{

// Initializing as both horizontal 
// and vertical symmetric.
boolean horizontal = true;
boolean vertical = true;

// Checking for Horizontal Symmetry. 
// We compare first row with last
// row, second row with second
// last row and so on.
for (int i = 0, k = N - 1; 
         i < N / 2; i++, k--)
{

    // Checking each cell of a column.
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {

        // check if every cell is identical
        if (arr[i][j] != arr[k][j])
        {
            horizontal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Checking for Vertical Symmetry. We compare
// first column with last column, second xolumn
// with second last column and so on.
for (int i = 0, k = M - 1;
         i < M / 2; i++, k--)
{

    // Checking each cell of a row.
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        // check if every cell is identical
        if (arr[i][j] != arr[k][j])
        {
            horizontal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!horizontal && !vertical)
    System.out.println("NO");

else if (horizontal && !vertical)
    System.out.println("HORIZONTAL");

else if (vertical && !horizontal)
    System.out.println("VERTICAL");

else
    System.out.println("BOTH");
}
```

**EDIT:**
After changing horitzontal = true for vertical = true,  the code still doesn't work propertly with rectangle Matrixes, so f.e. 4*2, giving me an array out of bounds.. 
Matrix:

```
1112
2212
```

with row = 2 and column = 4..

Comment: Uh... you set `vertical` to `true` and never, under any circumstances, set it to anything else.

Comment: The second `horizontal = false;` should be `vertical = false;`.

Comment: "Please write to us at contribute@geeksforgeeks.org to report any issue with the above content." You should do so. There is the same issue in the code for all 4 languages.

Comment: perfect, thanks! I thought the code would be correct..

Comment: @lydiaP you should also read about using a debugger. You would quickly identify the issue here using a debugger. Also, never really trust that anything you find on the internet works. Even "authoritative" sources like Oracle docs will have typos and omissions.

Comment: And as an optimisation, one could leave both loops if a non-symmetry was found, not just the inner one.

Comment: Did an edit as it's still not working, and now getting an Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 static void checkHV(int [][]arr, int N,
            int M)
{

// Initializing as both horizontal 
// and vertical symmetric.
boolean horizontal = true;
boolean vertical = true;

// Checking for Horizontal Symmetry. 
// We compare first row with last
// row, second row with second
// last row and so on.
for (int i = 0, k = N - 1; 
         i < N / 2; i++, k--)
{

    // Checking each cell of a column.
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {

        // check if every cell is identical
        if (arr[i][j] != arr[k][j])
        {
            horizontal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Checking for Vertical Symmetry. We compare
// first column with last column, second xolumn
// with second last column and so on.
for (int i = 0, k = M - 1;
         i < M / 2; i++, k--)
{

    // Checking each cell of a row.
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        // check if every cell is identical
        if (arr[j][i] != arr[j][k])
        {
            vertical = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (!horizontal && !vertical)
    System.out.println("NO");

else if (horizontal && !vertical)
    System.out.println("HORIZONTAL");

else if (vertical && !horizontal)
    System.out.println("VERTICAL");

else
    System.out.println("BOTH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isSymmetricHorizontally(int[][] matrix) {
    for(int rowL = 0, rowH = matrix.length - 1; rowL < rowH; rowL++, rowH--)
        for(int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++)
            if(matrix[rowL][col] != matrix[rowH][col])
                return false;
    
    return true;
}

public static boolean isSymmetricVertically(int[][] matrix) {
    for(int colL = 0, colH = matrix[0].length - 1; colL < colH; colL++, colH--)
        for(int row = 0; row < matrix[0].length; row++)
            if(matrix[row][colL] != matrix[row][colL])
                return false;
    
    return true;
}
```